# finding similar steady states amongst multiple transition matrices (MARKOV CHAIN)

Tags: markov-process

i am using a base markov chain (rather its transition matrix) to find its steady state. Now i have a bunch of other markov chains with varying steady states. Is there some way i can figure out which of these are most similar to the base steady state ?

I must apologize if this is unclear but let me try to explain with an example what i am trying out.

I have the sales of a product (5 years, daily data) and i constructed a transition matrix using change in sales volume as states (-20%, -10%, 0, 10%, 20%). I found its steady state and now i have a bunch of other products whose matrices i have constructed. I need to find out those products that behave similar to this reference product. Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86331/how-can-i-compare-two-matrices

Comment: @rightskewed - thanks a ton for pointing me to the answer .. never occurred to me to check the math forums (strangely enough) ..